# converting guitar to midi to use with learning software

Tags: midi, vst, audio-interfaces, learning

I found a lot of music learning software like [this](http://www.readmusicfree.com/notablyquickguitar.html#) which can accept midi input. Thing is I'm trying to learn guitar (and I don't want to buy a midi guitar).

Is there software that can do something like this:

1. Create a virtual midi device on my PC
2. Take the input from an audio interface I have my guitar connected to
3. Translate that input to midi
4. Output that midi data from the virtual midi device for use with
   programs like the one I linked to

I'm quite ignorant of this stuff so I'm also wondering if maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way? All I'm trying to accomplish is to use my guitar with music learning software that can tell me if I'm playing the "right" notes.

I have ableton. Is there a plugin that can translate the input from my guitar to midi and then somehow provide a virtual device other software can access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a guitar or any instrument for that matter from audio to midi is quite a difficult task. The solution you are looking for would best be suited with the game Rocksmith where they've done all the work of figuring out if you've played the right notes. It teaches guitar fairly well. The only downside is that if they don't have the song you want to learn you'll just have to do it the old fashion way.

That said there are solutions, none free that I know of. I just can't image jumping through a bunch of hoops with a hacked together solution is better than something designed for the very thing you're asking about, learning guitar.

[Intelliscore](http://www.intelliscore.net/audio-to-midi-tutorials.html) This is a software audio to midi converter
[Sonuus G2M](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/accessories/sonuus-g2m-universal-guitar-to-midi-converter) This is a hardware guitar input to midi output